# Why is Scrapy unable to get my URL once I configure my NTLM middleware?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy, middleware

I tried scraping yahoo.com prior to turning on my NTLM downloader middleware, and it worked perfectly. However, now that my downloader middleware is turned on in setting, I get an error saying "ERROR: Error downloading .

settings.py

```
    BOT_NAME = 'demo'

    SPIDER_MODULES = ['demo.spiders']
    NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'demo.spiders'

    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = { 'demo.ntlmauth.NtlmAuthMiddleware': 800, }

    ITEM_PIPELINES = [
                  'scrapysolr.SolrPipeline',
    ]

    SOLR_URL = 'solr_url'
    SOLR_MAPPING = {
       'id': 'url',
       'text': ['title', 'breadcrumbs', 'description'],
       'description': 'description',
       'keywords': 'breadcrumbs',
       'price': 'price',
       'title': 'title'
    }
```

ntlmauth.py. This code can also be found [here](https://github.com/reimund/ntlm-middleware/blob/master/ntlmauth.py).

```
    import os
    import urllib2
    from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler
    from scrapy.http import TextResponse

      class NtlmAuthMiddleware(object):

          def process_request(self, request, spider):
               usr = '%s\%s' % (os.environ["USERDOMAIN"], getattr(spider,'http_user', ''))
               pwd = getattr(spider, 'http_pass', '')
               url = request.url

               passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
               passman.add_password(None, url, usr, pwd)

               # Create the NTLM authentication handler.
               auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)

               # Create and install the opener.
               opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
               urllib2.install_opener(opener)

               # Retrieve the result.
               resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
               msg = resp.info()

                return HtmlResponse(url=url, status=resp.getcode(), headers=msg.items(), body=resp.read())
```

demo_Spider.py

```
   import scrapy

   class DemoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        http_user = 'DOMAIN\\USER'
        http_pass = 'PASSWORD'
        name = "demo"
        allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]
        start_urls = [ 
                "https://www.yahoo.com/" ]


        def parse(self, response):
                filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
                with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                     f.write(response.body)
```

And [here](http://apaste.info/uqi) is the error I am getting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at line 9 of the ntlm middleware:

```
usr = '%s\%s' % (os.environ["USERDOMAIN"], getattr(spider,'http_user', ''))
```

The error being raised is a result of not having the Environment Variable `USERDOMAIN` set.

In your current code, the value of `usr` will be 'OsUserDomain\DOMAIN\USER', which isn't likely what you want (it makes no sense).  I'd recommend you modify your spider, or the middleware, to use the correct 'domain\user' format.

Comment: what does USERDOMAIN mean? In addition, for the spider, am I supposed to put a real username and password or keep it as 'DOMAIN\\USERNAME, PASSWORD'

Comment: If you don't know what the Domain, User and Password you're supplying is, or what it is for, you should really get yourself more familiar with it all (and review you need this middleware at all).  I'd recommend you read up on what NTLM is, what the python `ntlm` package does, and how the Downloader Middleware works.  Keep in mind, the middleware is nearly 2 years old, and may not work with the more recently updated `ntlm` package.